# Adding and removing WPF UIElements at runtime

Tags: wpf, uielement

Is there a way to logically group or tag UIElements like shapes and controls added at runtime for easy removal?

For eg., I have a `Grid` with some (design-time) child elements and add Ellipses and `TextBlock`s to it at runtime. When I want to draw a different set of Ellipses and `TextBlock`s, I'd like to remove the original set I added. What would be an easy way to logically group these while adding them so I can just have a  children.clear() or some way to identify them to remove them?

It is possible to add a tag value but there is no way to retrieve or read this while iterating through children of a control because they are of type `UIElement` which does not have a tag property.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very good place to use an `Attached Property`.

### Example:

```
// Create an attached property named `GroupID`
public static class UIElementExtensions
{
    public static Int32 GetGroupID(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Int32)obj.GetValue(GroupIDProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGroupID(DependencyObject obj, Int32 value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GroupIDProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GroupID.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupIDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GroupID", typeof(Int32), typeof(UIElementExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Usage:

```
public void AddChild(UIElement element, Int32 groupID)
{
    UIElementExtensions.SetGroupID(element, groupID);
    rootPanel.Children.Add(element);
}

public void RemoveChildrenWithGroupID(Int32 groupID)
{
    var childrenToRemove = rootPanel.Children.OfType<UIElement>().
                           Where(c => UIElementExtensions.GetGroupID(c) == groupID);

    foreach (var child in childrenToRemove)
    {
        rootPanel.Children.Remove(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: this was really useful and works great for me. Thanks a lot. I have not yet been able to get the query for the remove part working because my parent element is a user control and so the type is different from a panel, but that should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

Try drawing on a `Canvas` inside your grid... that way its as easy as:

```
MyCanvas.Chlidren.Clear();
MyCanvas.Children.Add(new Ellipse { Canvas.Top = 3....});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but there are design-time children in there that I do not want to clear

Comment: Then put those you dont want to clear in an array [using x:Name], then loop trough the canvas children, clearing anything not in the array